# NumPy: Efficient way to multiply each pair of 3D matrices in two 4D matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I have two 4d matrices in NumPy whose height, width, and depth are the same.

```py
x = np.random.random((125,3,4,4)).astype(np.float32)
y = np.random.random((14,3,4,4)).astype(np.float32)
```

I want to multiply each 3d matrix in x with each 3d matrix in y such that the result is a 5d matrix with shape res[x.shape[0],y.shape[0],...]. Currently, I am following this code.

```py
xb,xd,xh,xw = x.shape
yb,yd,yh,yw = y.shape

res = np.zeros((xb,yb,xd,xh,xw))
for i in range(xb):
    for j in range(yb):
        res[i,j,...] = np.multiply(x[i,...],y[j,...])
```

Is there any other way to achieve this without loops? Some faster NumPy way?

Comment: Try broadcasting, `x[:, None]*y[None,:]` (the trailing dimensions are filled in automatically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can extend the dimension and of x and y to be 5 and repeat values on the available 4 dimensions alonge the new dimension, so that x and y have the same (125,14,3,4,4) shape. Then you can use elementwise multiplication as you do within the nested for loop:

```
x = np.random.random((125,3,4,4)).astype(np.float32)
y = np.random.random((14,3,4,4)).astype(np.float32)
x = np.repeat(x[:,np.newaxis,:,:,:], 14, axis=1)
y = np.repeat(y[np.newaxis,:,:,:,:], 125, axis=0)
xy = np.multiply(x,y)
```